# Define custom bugcheck codes in WinDbg

Tags: windows, windbg, device-driver, kernel

Is there a way to define custom codes (with messages/descriptions and whatnot) so that when, in a kernel-mode driver in Windows, I call `KeBugCheckEx` to issue a custom BugCheck code, WinDbg displays the associated message that comes with that custom bugcheck code?

Comment: Could you not use the `DbgPrintEx` or `KdPrintEx` to display output to the debugger? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @EdChum - Yes, That would be the easy way. However, I'm asking if WinDbg has a way to define custom BC codes. Not how to output to the debugger.

Comment: depending on the purpose for your request WPP tracing might be useful (if you want to be able to get messages from your driver without being able to attach a debugger)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text about the known bugcheck codes is compiled into one of the extension DLLs. This isn't something that's extensible in any kind of easy way as far as I know (i.e. you can't just add text to a file someplace).

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you:

[KeRegisterBugCheckCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and also read this:

http://www.osronline.com/custom.cfm?name=articlePrint.cfm&id=82

I only tested custom BSOD, not whole Bugcheck. :-)

Comment: Nothing to do with the question; that's just to catch the codes themselves. I just want to define custom messages for windbg itself.

Comment: I fail two times to help you. Sorry. :-(