# How can I get the BSOD bugcheck code text description by code/windows API

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg, bsod

I can get the bugcheck code and the parameters for one BSOD.

And then I can get the text descriptions from [Bug Check Code Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-code-reference2).

But how can I use some windows API or c++ code to get such text description from the bugcheck code and parameters.

For example, for the bugcheck code 0x9F, how can I get the text as

> DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
> A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.

with some windows API or reading from some DLL.

Or to say, how to implement similar function as WinDbg :

```
1: kd> !analyze -show 0x9F 0x3
DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: 0000000000000000, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: 0000000000000000, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: 0000000000000000, The blocked IRP
```

I saw there's API like KeGetBugMessageText(), but it's preserved by Windows itself.

Could someone help on this and give some clue or suggestion on that?

Update:
The main part of code used to execute command with 'blabb' suggestion:

```
#pragma comment ( lib ,"dbgeng.lib")
#include <iostream>
#include <dbgeng.h>
#include "StdioOutputCallbacks.h"

//#include <wdbgexts.h>
//WINDBG_EXTENSION_APIS64 ExtensionApis;
StdioOutputCallbacks g_OutputCb;
int main()
{
    IDebugClient* DebugClient = NULL;
    HRESULT Hr = S_OK;

    if ((Hr = DebugCreate(__uuidof(IDebugClient),
       (void**)&DebugClient)) != S_OK) {
       return Hr;
    }
    
    PDEBUG_CONTROL DebugControl;
    if ((Hr = DebugClient->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugControl),
       (void**)&DebugControl)) == S_OK) {
       DebugClient->SetOutputCallbacks(&g_OutputCb);

       Hr = DebugClient->OpenDumpFile("C:\\Dev\\Deem\\bug\\dcp938\\MEMORY.DMP");
       if (Hr != S_OK) {
          return Hr;
       }
       
       DebugControl->Execute(DEBUG_OUTCTL_THIS_CLIENT, "!analyze -show 9f 3", DEBUG_EXECUTE_DEFAULT);
       DebugControl->Release();
    }
    // done
    DebugClient->Release();
}
and in outputcallback, kept as the msdn sample:
STDMETHODIMP
StdioOutputCallbacks::Output(
   THIS_
   _In_ ULONG Mask,
   _In_ PCSTR Text
)
{
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Mask);
   fputs(Text, stdout);
   return S_OK;
}
```

But the result of the execute "!analyze -show 9f 3"(the content of Text in fputs()) is "No export analyze found".
I also try the command ".opendump C:\...MEMORY.DMP;!analyze -show 9f 3", the opendump command executed correctly, the dmp is loaded and got the text output including "For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v", but both "!analyze -v" and "!analyze -show ..." got "No export analyze found".
The command without '!' will lead to command resolve error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another answer as the prior answer is too cluttered and commented.

contents of directory pre compilation and linking

```
F:\bugdesc>ls -lg
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 156689581 Aug 17 23:49 MEMORY.DMP                                                                   
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121       600 Aug 26 01:22 bugdesc.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121       109 Aug 19 00:04 complink.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121      1019 Aug 26 01:21 stdioimpl.h
```

contents of bat file

```
F:\bugdesc>cat complink.bat
cl  /nologo /W4 /Od  /Zi /EHsc /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\inc" %1.cpp /link /RELEASE
```

file containing implementation of StdioOutputCallbacks

```
F:\bugdesc>cat stdioimpl.h
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dbgeng.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dbgeng.lib")
class StdioOutputCallbacks : public IDebugOutputCallbacks {
public:
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(THIS_ _In_ REFIID ifid, _Out_ PVOID *iface);
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, AddRef)(THIS);
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Release)(THIS);
    STDMETHOD(Output)(THIS_ IN ULONG Mask, IN PCSTR Text);
};
STDMETHODIMP
StdioOutputCallbacks::QueryInterface(THIS_ _In_ REFIID ifid, _Out_ PVOID *iface){
    *iface = NULL;
    if (IsEqualIID(ifid, __uuidof(IDebugOutputCallbacks))){
        *iface = (IDebugOutputCallbacks *)this;
        AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }    else    {
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
}
STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG)
StdioOutputCallbacks::AddRef(THIS) { return 1; }
STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG)
StdioOutputCallbacks::Release(THIS) { return 0; }
STDMETHODIMP StdioOutputCallbacks::Output(THIS_ IN ULONG, IN PCSTR Text){
    fputs(Text, stdout);
    return S_OK;
}
```

contents of main source file

```
F:\bugdesc>cat bugdesc.cpp
#include "stdioimpl.h"
//implement proper error handling and release of Interfaces
void __cdecl main(void)
{
    IDebugClient *g_Client;
    IDebugControl *g_Control;
    StdioOutputCallbacks g_OutputCb;
    DebugCreate(__uuidof(IDebugClient), (void **)&g_Client);
    g_Client->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugControl), (void **)&g_Control);
    g_Client->SetOutputCallbacks(&g_OutputCb);
    g_Client->SetOutputCallbacks(&g_OutputCb);
    g_Client->OpenDumpFile("F:\\bugdesc\\memory.dmp");
    g_Control->WaitForEvent(0, INFINITE);
    g_Control->Execute(0, "!analyze -show 9f 3", 0);
}
```

compiled and linked with vs-community 2017 as x64

```
F:\bugdesc>complink.bat bugdesc

F:\bugdesc>cl  /nologo /W4 /Od  /Zi /EHsc /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\inc" bugdesc.cpp /link /RELEASE
bugdesc.cpp
```

contents of directory post compilation and linking

```
F:\bugdesc>ls -lg
total 159485
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 156689581 Aug 17 23:49 MEMORY.DMP
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121       600 Aug 26 01:22 bugdesc.cpp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 197121    406016 Aug 26 01:25 bugdesc.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121     30072 Aug 26 01:25 bugdesc.obj
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121   5992448 Aug 26 01:25 bugdesc.pdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121       109 Aug 19 00:04 complink.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121      1019 Aug 26 01:21 stdioimpl.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121    176128 Aug 26 01:25 vc140.pdb
```

executing without proper dlls and failure

```
F:\bugdesc>bugdesc.exe
No .natvis files found at C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Visualizers.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx snip 
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.18362.1 AMD64
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx snip
Loading Dump File [F:\bugdesc\memory.dmp]
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx snip
***    Type referenced: nt!_MMPTE_TRANSITION                          ***
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx snip
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
No export analyze found<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

copying relevent dlls from windbg installation folder

```
F:\bugdesc>copy ..\windbg_dlls\*.* .
..\windbg_dlls\dbgeng.dll
..\windbg_dlls\dbghelp.dll
..\windbg_dlls\ext.dll
..\windbg_dlls\symsrv.dll
        4 file(s) copied.
```

execution and success

```
F:\bugdesc>bugdesc.exe

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 AMD64
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx snip
Loading Dump File [F:\bugdesc\memory.dmp]
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx snip
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck E2, {0, 0, 0, 0}

Probably caused by : Unknown_Image
 *** Followup info cannot be found !!! Please contact "BADEV"

---------

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: 0000000000000000, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: 0000000000000000, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: 0000000000000000, The blocked IRP
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx snip
```

Comment: It's really appreciated! I get the text description now after copy the dlls. And another tip is that it's be build to x64 version.

Comment: ok if it solved the problem mark it as such

Comment: 32 bit 64 bit have separate dlls build and copy relevent dlls. also check LoadExtension (). , CallExtension(). methods

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are looking for.
All these are #defined in bugcodes.h in windows sdk/ddk

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include>pss DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
.\10.0.17763.0\shared\bugcodes.h
1505:// MessageId: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
1509://  DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
1511:#define DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE       ((ULONG)0x0000009FL)
```

Or grepping the other way round

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include>grep -ir #define.*0x0000009fl --include *.h *
10.0.17763.0/shared/bugcodes.h:#define DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE       ((ULONG)0x0000009FL)
```

Or use DbgEng to write either a WinDbg extension or a standalone executable.

Open the dump->WaitForEvent->Executecommands   !bugdump .bug****

Or you can also explore `IDebugDataSpaces::****tag****` methods like read, start, next, end.

Edit

Scott Noone is probably indicating the ext.dll the inbuilt windbg extension

As i Already Stated you may need to write a windbg Analyze Extension either as an extension or as a standalone
most of these are either undocumented or poorly worded documentation

here is the dump of bugcheck codes compiled inside ext.dll which is what scott noone is probably indicating in his answer.

```
0:000> dps ext!g_BugCheckApiRefs l10
00007ff9`4a45ccc0  00000000`00000001
00007ff9`4a45ccc8  00007ff9`49efead0 ext!BugCheckAPC_INDEX_MISMATCH
00007ff9`4a45ccd0  00000000`00000002
00007ff9`4a45ccd8  00007ff9`49efeb60 ext!BugCheckDEVICE_QUEUE_NOT_BUSY
00007ff9`4a45cce0  00000000`00000003
00007ff9`4a45cce8  00007ff9`49efebc0 ext!BugCheckINVALID_AFFINITY_SET
00007ff9`4a45ccf0  00000000`00000004
00007ff9`4a45ccf8  00007ff9`49efec20 ext!BugCheckINVALID_DATA_ACCESS_TRAP
00007ff9`4a45cd00  00000000`00000005
00007ff9`4a45cd08  00007ff9`49efec80 ext!BugCheckINVALID_PROCESS_ATTACH_ATTEMPT
00007ff9`4a45cd10  00000000`00000006
00007ff9`4a45cd18  00007ff9`49efece0 ext!BugCheckINVALID_PROCESS_DETACH_ATTEMPT
00007ff9`4a45cd20  00000000`00000007
00007ff9`4a45cd28  00007ff9`49efed40 ext!BugCheckINVALID_SOFTWARE_INTERRUPT
00007ff9`4a45cd30  00000000`00000008
00007ff9`4a45cd38  00007ff9`49efeda0 ext!BugCheckIRQL_NOT_DISPATCH_LEVEL
0:000>
```

or your power failure

```
0:000> .shell -ci "dps ext!g_BugCheckApiRefs l150" grep -A 1 -i 09f
00007ff9`4a45d600  00000000`0000009f
00007ff9`4a45d608  00007ff9`49f04450 ext!BugCheckDRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
.shell: Process exited
0:000>
```

here is a complete call stackLeadign to yourQuery about !analyze -show 9f 3

```
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
000000d3`6d67b768 00007ff9`49fa302a ext!GetBugCheckDescription
000000d3`6d67b770 00007ff9`49f822c2 ext!DebugFailureAnalysis::ParseInputArgs+0xc66
000000d3`6d67bb00 00007ff9`49f549c5 ext!AnalyzeBugCheck+0x10a
000000d3`6d67bbd0 00007ff9`4ae0187d ext!analyze+0x4e5
000000d3`6d67bd90 00007ff9`4ae01a31 dbgeng!ExtensionInfo::CallA+0x27d
000000d3`6d67be50 00007ff9`4ae01d0e dbgeng!ExtensionInfo::Call+0x121
000000d3`6d67c050 00007ff9`4adff9d8 dbgeng!ExtensionInfo::CallAny+0x17a
000000d3`6d67c570 00007ff9`4ae43662 dbgeng!ParseBangCmd+0xe0c
000000d3`6d67cd30 00007ff9`4ae44635 dbgeng!ProcessCommands+0xcd6
000000d3`6d67ce20 00007ff9`4ad6baf7 dbgeng!ProcessCommandsAndCatch+0x79
000000d3`6d67ce90 00007ff9`4ad6be04 dbgeng!Execute+0x2bb
000000d3`6d67d380 00007ff6`4c7b62dc dbgeng!DebugClient::ExecuteWide+0x94
000000d3`6d67d3e0 00007ff6`4c7b879a kd!MainLoop+0x514
000000d3`6d67f460 00007ff6`4c7bb55d kd!wmain+0x3e6
000000d3`6d67f700 00007ff9`857c7c24 kd!__wmainCRTStartup+0x14d
000000d3`6d67f740 00007ff9`85d8d721 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
000000d3`6d67f770 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
0:000>
```

The Function is a simple compare return routine like

```
while array[i] != 0x9f skip 
return String array[i]+0x8
```

and the detailed description is done by

```
void PrintBugDescription(_BUGCHECK_ANALYSIS *param_1,DebugFailureAnalysis *param_2)
```

EDIT
Since My last comment I was wondering

1. how I would go about this scenario without writing code
2. without having a kernel memory dump to operate on
3. possibly scalable to unknown remote machines

I Came up with a small python wrapper using sysinternals livekd.exe

script

```
:\>cat liv.py
import subprocess
import regex
foo = subprocess.run(
    [r"f:\sysint\livekd", "-b" ,"-c \"!analyze -show 9f 03;q\""],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True
    )
resta = regex.search("Reading" , foo.stdout).start()
reend = regex.search("quit:" , foo.stdout).end()
print(foo.stdout[resta:reend])
```

result of script execution

```
:\>python liv.py
Reading initial command '!analyze -show 9f 03;q'
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for LiveKdD.SYS
DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: 0000000000000000, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: 0000000000000000, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: 0000000000000000, The blocked IRP
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 0, {0, 0, 0, 0}

Probably caused by : LiveKdD.SYS ( LiveKdD+2f4f )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

quit:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!    <br/> The thing I want is: Given the input '0x9F', the output should be 'DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f) A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.'   <br/> 

So bugcodes.h does not include the detailed description of the bugcheck code, where can I retrieve it from?  <br/>  Thanks!

Comment: Or from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035784/define-custom-bugcheck-codes-in-windbg, "Text about the known bugcheck codes is compiled into one of the extension DLLs.",  What's the dll name and how to get the text from the dll?

Comment: added info take a look

Comment: Thank you so much! That very helpful. I will check more details on the windbg GetBugCheckDescription and PrintBugDescription. Thanks!

Comment: they are not exported so you cant LoadLib->Getproc and call also if you happen to bend it to load and call you do not have a dump to read and none of the Idebug interfaces will have been initialized like you would have if you used Dbgeng->IDebugClient->OpenDump()   so as far as i  can tell you would be writing a windbg clone and passing the string to IdebugControl->Execute("show 9f 3")

Comment: It's very appreciated, blabb! I did learn from it. I have the access to the dump file but I do not want to use windbg or livekd.exe or any other tools in my code. I wish to use some code and some windows API or library to implement it. As your mentioned, I can use IDebugClient::OpenDumpFile(), but then what's the next? I went through the functions of IDebugControl and IDebugClient, but did not get too much clue in short time. Is there any key/major APi can be used to get the text description eventually? Thanks a lot!

Comment: i already mentioned IDebugControl::Execute("command string to execute"  )

Comment: Ah, I did not realized that 'show 9f 3' is an already existing function/command as I did not find it in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/commands. I thought I would have to implement the 'show 9f 3' command by myself. It's very appreciated, I will have a try and update the result.

Comment: it is not show 9f 3. it must be full command as you execute in windbg prompt. like "!analyze -show 9f 3". i dont remember off hand if you need the ! bang or not so you may have to try both with and without bang

Comment: It's really appreciated for the kind correction. I will try the code and update the result. Thanks!

Comment: I tried with IDebugControl::Execute, and the code is as updated in the question. But the result of the execute "!analyze -show 9f 3"(the content of Text in fputs()) is "No export analyze found". I also try the command ".opendump C:\...MEMORY.DMP;!analyze -show 9f 3", the opendump command executed correctly, the dmp is loaded and got the text output including "For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v", but both "!analyze -v" and "!analyze -show ..." got "No export analyze found". The command without '!' will lead to command resolve error.

Comment: ext.dll isn't loaded try copying both the dump file and your compiled exe to windbg installation folder and test

Comment: Added another answer take a look